# Sort by frequency using the key argument not working as expected

Tags: python, list, sorting

A given array is to be sorted on the basis of the frequency of occurrence of its elements.

I tried using `key=arr.count` (`arr` is the name of the list I want to sort). It works for some inputs. I also tried using the `collections.Counter()` class object, it behaved similarly to how `arr.count` did.

```
>>> arr = [6, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2]
>>> sorted(arr, key=arr.count)
[6, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2]
>>> sorted(arr, key=counts.get)
[6, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2]
```

Expected output is:

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 6 6 6

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: 4 and 6 have the same count, so your output fits your criteria. You need an additional criteria if you want to separate items of same count.

Comment: Using arr.count in this way is an incredibly inefficient way of sorting by frequency `O(n**2*log(n))`. Using collections.Counter way would've been a lot more efficient and more clearer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tuple to sort first by frequency and then by value, for inverting the ordering you can use `-` (so smallest numbers comes first), and then since you want the biggest count first use reverse:

```
sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (arr.count(x), -x), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that some entries have the same frequency, e.g.:

```
arr.count(1) == arr.count(2) == arr.count(7)
```

To make sure that these entries remain grouped, you have to sort not only by counts, but also by value:

```
counts = collections.Counter(arr)
sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (counts[x], x), reverse=True)
```

Output:
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4]